# 2021 Toyota Venza Lighter Fuse Location

Tags: electrical, fuse

I had a radar detector hooked up to cigarette lighter outlet when all of a sudden the outlet lost power. I tested with other 12V cig cables to confirm and it indeed has no power.

As the first step in troubleshooting I wanted to replace the fuse but none of the fuses are labeled as CIG or anything similar.

Anyone know which fuse is assigned to the cigarette lighter outlet?

[image]

EDIT: Apparently, as pointed out by @HandyHowie, there is another fuse box inside the cabin, on the driver's side where the fuse for cigarette lighter is located. It is a 15A fuse and the label is `P/OUTLET NO.1`. This fuse box is not visible until you dive in head first under the steering wheel and look up.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fuse you want will be in the passenger compartment.

The [user manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2309851/Toyota-Venza-2021.html?page=427#manual) for the vehicle shows the fuse box location -

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's highly inaccessible. You have to literally dive in head first under the steering wheel to even see it.